# Schedule Triggered Flow Error

Tags: scheduled-flow

I've created a schedule triggered flow, which is supposed to send an email to the record's owner and has the following condition:
[image: KYC Renewal Due Date equals today's date]

This is the recipient email list: {!$Record.Owner:User.Email}

I updated the record's owner to me and the renewal due date to today's date. However, the email wasn't sent.

In the debug I receive this text:

emailAddresses = {!$Record.Owner:User.Email} (janedoe@XXX.com)

emailSubject = Test

emailBody = Test

Outputs

None.

Does anyone know what do I need to correct in the flow to send out the email successfully?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you check your salesforce org's `Deliverability` settings? Is that `Access level` Settings available as "All Emails" instead of "No Access"?

Comment: Yes, it is "All Emails", checked that already. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: when you debugged; did you run the flow in `Rollback mode`? - if yes, no email would be sent

Comment: No, I used this: "Debug pause element behavior"

Comment: It was indeed the Deliverability settings, Access level Settings was set to "No Access". I checked the wrong Sandbox before. Thanks to all for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed the Deliverability settings, Access level Settings was set to "No Access".